# How do we assign a value to a variable and display the value without the aid of scripts?

Tags: html, css

This is a long shot (it may not be possible w/o scripting).  On my website I would like to set numerical values one time (perhaps in the .css file?).

Example:

```
shipping_1 = 3.99
shipping_2 = 4.25
shipping_3 = 7.58
```

and be able to reference these shipping rates by name on various pages and have the numerical value display (it could even be text because no calculations would be made).  The purpose is change the shipping values one time in one file and have them updated on the various pages.

Comment: Depends how you implement the website. But I would not go down the "magic number" rabbit hole. Ideally these numbers should be in some form of database that is accessible/updateable from every page that needs them.  In a pinch, you could use session variables to test functionality, but without proper persistence, the values would get reset each time you start a session.

Comment: While you could use CSS variables and perhaps display them as content, I suspect that may not be what you mean given the phrase' referene these... by name' Could you explain more?

Comment: So I have an HTML page for each product.  On that page I provide the item cost and the shipping cost.  I would like to be able to edit the values for item cost and shipping cost in one html or css file rather than opening each HTML page and performing the edit.  I am not a savvy programmer so scripting or db is out of reach for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use just CSS then you could have something like this in a CSS file:

```
:root {
--sv1: '3.2';
--sv2: '4.2';
--sv3: '3.1';
}
.sv1::after {
  content: var(--sv1);
}
.sv2::after {
  content: var(--sv2);
}
.sv3::after {
  content: var(--sv3);
}
```

and in each of your pages you could just bring in the value that page represents e.g.:

```
<div class="sv2">Shipping value: </div>
```

However, I do not recommend it in the general case because screen readers may not read out the contents part (as CSS is really for styling not for actual real content) so someone relying on a screen reader may not hear the actual price.

Comment: That is interesting.  I think it is time for me to step up.  I will apply some basic PHP to accomplish this task.  Thank you for showing me this option.